# Resolve symbolic links when copying bundle resources in Xcode

Tags: xcode, symlink

I have a project in Xcode and some resources for the project. The resources contain several symbolic links. When Xcode builds the project, it copies the resources, but does not resolve the symbolic links. Is there a way to tell Xcode to resolve the links? (Ie. have the link targets copied instead of the links themselves.)

*Update:* Thanks, mouviciel, that was almost it. At first I tried to do it using the Copy Files phase, but the `pbxcp` program called by this phase did not resolve the links either, even though there is some switch called `-resolve-src-symlinks`. I ended up adding a Run Script phase calling something like this:

```
rsync -pvtrlL --cvs-exclude \
    $PROJECT_DIR/../Resources* \
    $BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR/$CONTENTS_FOLDER_PATH
```

Fortunate side effect is that I no longer need to keep the Resources group in Xcode updated, whatever changes done in the Resources directory are immediately visible.

Comment: Did you, over time, come to a better solution? I'd appreciate if you shared it :)

Comment: Well, after testing your solution I find it elegant and concise, thanks for sharing! :)

Comment: This works perfectly!!! Thank you man! You saved me hours of frustration with Phonegap shared files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A solution could be to insert a Run Script Build Phase which performs the copy exactly the way you want, i.e., by dereferencing symbolic links (this is the default behaviour of cp).